# Link to specific Oracle instant client dynamic library on OS X

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos, oracle, oci8

There's a widely-used Ruby gem (ruby-oci8) which uses a C-extension to call an Oracle C library (Oracle Instant Client).  It creates a bundle (oci8lib_191.bundle) which calls routines in the the Oracle library (libclntsh.dylib.11.1).

However, if one uses LDAP to resolve their database name, there's a problem.  The client crashes with:

```
Assertion failed: (LDAP_VALID( ld )), function ldap_first_entry, file getentry.c, line 35.
```

The Oracle library includes its own LDAP routines.

```
nm /Applications/OracleInstantClient/libclntsh.dylib.11.1 | grep ldap_first_entry
0000000000f0fc50 T _ldap_first_entry
0000000000f15620 T _ora_ldap_first_entry
```

However, I've verified using gdb that when the client crashes, it crashes inside the code for the OS X LDAP library.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff8403d212 in __pthread_kill ()
#1  0x00007fff8da78af4 in pthread_kill ()
#2  0x00007fff8dabcdce in abort ()
#3  0x00007fff8dabde2a in __assert_rtn ()
#4  0x00007fff86e233e2 in ldap_first_entry ()

(gdb) info symbol 0x00007fff86e233e2
ldap_first_entry + 98 in section LC_SEGMENT.__TEXT.__text of /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP
```

So, apparently what is happening is when the bundle tries to call ldap_first_entry(), it's linked with the OS X version instead of Oracle's custom version inside (libclntsh.dylib.11.1).

My first thought was to use the same trick used to link a static library when a dynamic library is present. That is, pass the absolute path to the library.  However, as you can see, that results in an error:

```
gcc -dynamic -bundle -o oci8lib_191.bundle oci8lib.o env.o error.o oci8.o ocihandle.o connection_pool.o stmt.o bind.o metadata.o attr.o lob.o oradate.o ocinumber.o ocidatetime.o object.o apiwrap.o encoding.o oranumber_util.o thread_util.o -L. -L/usr/local/lib -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-flat_namespace  -L/Applications/OracleInstantClient -l/Applications/OracleInstantClient/libclntsh.dylib.11.1 -lpthread -ldl -lobjc 
ld: library not found for -l/Applications/OracleInstantClient/libclntsh.dylib.11.1
```

The library does exist at the path listed:

```
xanadu:~ wwilliam$ file /Applications/OracleInstantClient/libclntsh.dylib.11.1
/Applications/OracleInstantClient/libclntsh.dylib.11.1: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

I also tried -rpath:

```
gcc -dynamic -bundle -o oci8lib_191.bundle oci8lib.o env.o error.o oci8.o ocihandle.o connection_pool.o stmt.o bind.o metadata.o attr.o lob.o oradate.o ocinumber.o ocidatetime.o object.o apiwrap.o encoding.o oranumber_util.o thread_util.o -L. -L/usr/local/lib -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-flat_namespace  -L/Applications/OracleInstantClient -Wl,-rpath,/Applications/OracleInstantClient -lclntsh -lpthread -ldl -lobjc
```

FYI, DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is set:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/Applications/OracleInstantClient
```

So, how can ensure the bundle links with the Oracle version of ldap_first_entry ()?

I'm using OS X 10.8.2 with Xcode Version 4.6 (4H127).

Comment: Even though the oci8lib_191.bundle surely links with the libclntsh.dylib.11.1, the client crashes as long as OS X version LDAP is loaded in advance. When two libraries include same symbol, the first loaded library's symbol is used.

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

I mailed with the questioner and the crash disappeared by adding "require 'oci8'" at the top of his application.

According the log outputted by DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and DYLD_PRINT_BINDINGS=1, this issue was caused by function interposition. The libclntsh.dylib and the OS X LDAP library export _ldap_first_entry whose implementation differs. When the OS X LDAP libary is loaded into the process memory before libclntsh.dylib and a function in libclntsh.dylib tries to use _ldap_first_entry in libclntsh.dylib, it faulty uses _ldap_first_entry in the OS X LDAP library.
It may happen on Unix (except OS X) generally and on OS X only when a library is linked with flat_namespace.

IMO, he doesn't use the OS X LDAP library explicitly. He uses a kind of authorization module, which depends on the library internally.

The rest is not changed.

---

I have an idea. But I haven't tested it.

IMO, ruby doesn't use OS X version library directly. A extension library such ruby-ldap uses it. If so, "require 'oci8'" before the extension library may solve the issue.

```
require 'oci8' # This must be before any other extension libraries using LDAP.
require 'ldap' # for example
```

But it causes another issue. When the ruby-ldap library try to use OS X version _ldap_first_entry, Oracle version _ldap_first_entry is called and the process crashes. You need to customize oci8 to avoid it.

Change `DLOPEN_FLAG` in ext/oci8/oci8lib.c as follows,

```
#define DLOPEN_FLAG (RTLD_NOW|RTLD_LOCAL)
```

then install as follows

```
gem build ruby-oci8.gemspec
gem install ruby-oci8-2.1.5.gem -- --with-runtime-check
```

and use it.

```
require 'oci8' # This must be before any other extension libraries using LDAP.
require 'ldap'
```

`RTLD_LOCAL` hides symbols in libclntsh.dylib from other extension libraries.
`RTLD_NOW` resolves symbols immediately and prevents libclntsh.dylib from using symbols in succeedingly loaded libraries.
`--with-runtime-check` forces ruby-oci8 to use dlopen().

I hope that OS X dlopen() specification is same with Linux and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'otool -L < path to dylib >' to dump the dylibs that your executable or dylibs are dependent on. They should have been built to access the bundle frameworks via a relative path ('@executable_path/../Frameworks/*' (or @loader_path or @rpath)) instead of the system ones.

See the "DYNAMIC LIBRARY LOADING" section of the dyld man page at: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html

The install_path of a dylib is used to tell the execs & dylibs that link against it where they should expect to find it at runtime. You can (try to) change the install_path of a dylib via the install_name_tool command line tool. (I say 'try' because it can fail silently so ALWAYS check afterwords to see if it actually worked.)

Comment: Thanks George. You're right. I've since learned the reason it's finding the Apple LDAP is because the recorded install_name doesn't exist.  I've passed `-Wl,-install_name,/location/of/library.dylib` to clang, but the resulting .bundle is still showing the old path.  I have a question open with DTS on why it's not working. I realize I could use install_name_tool, but I'm trying to solve the problem the right way for those who will compile after me.